# catkin_make install - setup.bash file not created?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
as I am completely new to CMake etc I do have a probably simple problem which I am not able to solve. Previously to asking here I read various tutorials but was not able to solve the following problem:
I do have 3 ros packages: pkg_a, pkg_b and pkg_c. pkg_a depends on pkg_b and pkg_c. As I do not want to share the source code of pkg_b and pkg_c I'd like to pass these packages on as an installed version. However, if I use "catkin_make install --pkg pkg_b pkg_c" the Install folder and the respective folders in the Install folder are generated but the files on the first level of the Install folder (e.g. setup.bash) are not generated. These files are only generated if I do "catkin_make install" without restricting the install to the named two packages. Is catkin_make install not foreseen to be used in the way I intend?

I am sure you need to provide more information to make to the problem solvable but I don't know which information is necessary. Please let me know.

Best regards!

**Edit:**
The plan in the next step is to delete pkg_b and pkg_c, source the Install folder and then compile pkg_a. But <catkin_make install --pkg pkg_b pkg_c> only gives the folders Include, Lib and Share but not the files
setup.sh, setup.bash and setup.zsh in the Include folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305283/catkin_make-install---setup.bash-file-not-created!?/) by [anonymous37982](https://answers.ros.org/users/37982/anonymous37982/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2018-10-09**:
What do you mean by "pass these packages on as an installed version"? I cannot really picture the problem you are trying to solve.

**Comment by [anonymous37982](https://answers.ros.org/users/37982/anonymous37982/) on 2018-10-09**:
Sorry. That's not important to the problem. I need to share my code, one part is intended to be shared as a source code such that it is manipulatable and the other part (pkg_b and _c) shall be shared as a installed version. Therefore I only want to build these two packages via catkin_make Install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really an answer to your question, if `catkin_make` can do this, as I don't know that.

But as a "work-around", you could easily set up [chained workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying), where `pkg_B` and `pkg_C` are in the underlay workspace and `pkg_A` in the overlay.
With this, you have the separation required so can just call `catkin_make install` on the underlay and can share this install space. (Note, that sharing install spaces is not that easy if you don't put them somewhere globally available. If you share the install space from within your home, you'll most likely run into problems...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous37982](https://answers.ros.org/users/37982/anonymous37982/) on 2018-10-10**:
Are nodes allowed in the underlaying workspaces?
Thanks for the new idea!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-10-10**:
Sure. Basically, also `/opt/ros/DISTRO` is an underlay. If you clone any package you have installed therein (say, `std_msgs`) into your `catkin_ws_overlay`, this one is used once you source the respective overlay workspace. The pkg still exists in the underlay but is "not discovered".

**Comment by [anonymous37982](https://answers.ros.org/users/37982/anonymous37982/) on 2018-10-10**:
Ok, thanks. I'll give it a try!